# grouped sum() partitioned by flexible interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have some data as follows (just a few example lines here, `tablesize > n` thousand entries)

```
timestamp         duration

2012-09-30T22:00  10800
2012-10-01T08:00   7200
2012-10-01T15:00   3600
2012-10-01T22:00  10800
2012-10-02T07:00   3600
2012-10-02T14:00  18000
```

and aim to achieve something like:

```
date               totalDuration

2012-09-30        21600
2012-10-01        32400
```

and so on.

Durations should be summed up per interval, whereby interval starts at `22:00` each day in this example. 
It's SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    cast(dateadd(hour, -22, date) as date), 
    sum(duration) totalDuration
from yourtable
group by cast(dateadd(hour, -22, date) as date)
```

However, you should note that `2012-09-30T22:00` and`2012-10-01T22:00` should not be in the same "time frame day". `2012-09-30T22:00` and `2012-10-01T21:59` can be in the same day.

Compare this to having thresholds like 1-10 and 10-20. Where does 10 belong to?

Comment: thanks. haven't seen the wood for the trees.
anyway - i use half-open intervals, eg. date >= start of interval and date < end of interval to assign data to interval.